# Click anchor tag open with localhost url (www.google.com)?

Tags: html

***Below is the  code***

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
```

***it's display next page url like below***

```
http://99.1.0.39/test/test-2/www.yahoo.com
```

How to open new page with www.yahoo.com?

Comment: https : // www.yahoo.com

Comment: Can you please tell me why we will put like that https://

Comment: www also valid right. @Roy please help me on this

Comment: The browser doesn't know that "www..." is *supposed* to represent a domain. What's the difference between `www.yahoo.com` and `foobar`? `foobar` is interpreted as a relative path, i.e. the "directory" `foobar`. What's different about `www.yahoo.com` that it should not be interpreted the same way? Nothing. You need a fully qualified URL to external domains, not just the host name.

Comment: I helped, use correct absolute path.. (best way is going to the site yahoo.com, copy the entire url and paste on href)

Comment: ok @roy,@deceze , always we have to give http:// or https://  right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML force URL hyperlink to be treated as non-relative (absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215162/html-force-url-hyperlink-to-be-treated-as-non-relative-absolute)

Answer (score 1):

### **Try using**

**If you are unsure about that protocol use**

```
<a href="//www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo!</a>
```